# Css Background image blur outside from div

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a background image and a very high blur applied on it. My problem is that the blur effect is also a bit outside from the div container, which is absolute positioned.

Problem is shown here

[image: 1]

```
<div class="p-2 position-relative bg-grey-secondary border-0 rounded-2 card">
    <div class="position-absolute w-100 h-100 bg" style="background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/70/Solid_white.svg/2048px-Solid_white.svg.png);"></div>
</div>

<style>
div > div {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    filter: blur(13px);
    opacity: 30%;
    mask-image: linear-gradient(to top, transparent, black);
}
</style>
```

```css
div>div {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  filter: blur(13px);
  opacity: 30%;
  mask-image: linear-gradient(to top, transparent, black);
}
```

```html
<div class="p-2 position-relative bg-grey-secondary border-0 rounded-2 card">
  <div class="position-absolute w-100 h-100 bg" style="background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/70/Solid_white.svg/2048px-Solid_white.svg.png);"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but try this and I request please write your question clearly

```
mask-image: linear-gradient(to top, transparent, black);
```

Comment: Aight, I hope my update helps to understand my problem better. Mask image didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure me too about the request but I'll try to answer, otherwise please provide a clearer example of the result you want to obtain...

**Are you looking for a glass effect blurring the background?**

```
backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
```

Your CSS will look like this:

```
<style>
div > div {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    /* comment blur filter, in this case not necessary*/ 
    /* filter: blur(13px); */
    opacity: 30%;
    mask-image: linear-gradient(to top, transparent, black);
    /* add filter to blur the objects behind the background */
    backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
}
</style>
```

**Some hints**: to modulate the glass effect mantain the backdrop-filter at low values and change the opacity of the object you are applying the filter.

Here is a live example of the effect.

The codepen here:
https://codepen.io/gesteves/pen/PwRPZa

Find the full explanation here, containing differences and usage of both blur filter and backdrop-filter and how to obtain the glass effect:
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/backdrop-filter/